# Adding attributes to Entity Framework autogenerated properties

Tags: entity-framework, properties, attributes, metadata

I need to add some attributes to properties that were autogenerated by Entity Framework and do not want to lose them when regenerating objects. I don't want to touch T4 either.

Looking interenet I found that the partial class can be added MetaDataType like:

```
<MetadataType(GetType(Employee_Metadata))> _
Partial Public Class employee
...
```

And then create another class where we add the actual metadata to properties:

```
Public Class Employee_Metadata

    <Category("General"), DisplayName("Name"), Description("Employee name.")> _
    Public Property employee_name() As String
        Get
            Return _employee_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _employee_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _employee_name As String

End Class
```

Now, what else I need to do to get access to the attributes? 
I am currently binding a UI component to class employee autogenerated property "employee_name" (using MVVM). Do I need to change further something in my partial class or should I change the databinding itself (WPF in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

1. Choose a different name for the mapped property in the designer (e.g. **employee_name_private**) and mark both setter and getter in the designer as **Private**.
2. In a partial class file define the **public** property with the required attributes:

   ```
   Partial Public Class Employee

       <Category("General"), DisplayName("Name"), Description("Employee name.")> _
       Public Property employee_name() As String
           Get
               Return employee_name_private
           End Get
           Set(value As String)
               employee_name_private = value
           End Set
       End Property

   End Class
   ```